# what is the difference of button with class?

Tags: html, css

```css
.title_Btn{
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button><i class="fas fa-caret-down title_Btn"></i></button>
```

---

If I change ".title_Btn" to "button" in css , It work well
But I don't know why ".title_Btn" is not work.
I make a class "title_Btn" in button.
What 's my mistake?

Comment: You are putting the class on `i` not `button`. If you move the class to the `button` element, it should work as expected

Comment: the class is in the `i` element!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.title_Btn{
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
}

<button class="title_Btn"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

The problem arose because you put the class inside the 'i' tag and not inside the  tag..

Answer (score 2):

You should apply the styling for the button inside the button tag:

```css
.title_Btn{
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="title_Btn"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have added the title_Btn class to the `<i>` tag add it to the `<button>` tag
Like this:

```css
.title_Btn{
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="title_Btn"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `title_Btn` inside the `<button>` and not in `<i>` tag.

HTML:

```
<button class="title_Btn"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

CSS:

```
.title_Btn{
        background-color: Transparent;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        border: none;
        cursor:pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        outline:none;
    }
```